# 2-sum algorithm weight calculation

Tags: algorithm

I started taking the course about algorithms and get stuck with **2-sum algorithm** weight calculation (and 3-sum and so on).

**There is a simple 1-sum example**:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    if (a[i] == 0)
        count ++
```

Where N is just number - exact value doesn't matter.

And there are next parameters:

- variable declaration: 2
- assignment statement: 2
- less than compare: N + 1
- equal to compare: N
- array access: N
- increment: N to 2N

and so on - it's clear

**But the next is 2-sum example**:

```
int count = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
      if (a[i] + a[j] == 0)
          count ++
```

And there are another parameters:

- variable declaration: N + 2
- assignment statement: N + 2
- **less than compare: (1/2) (N + 1) (N + 2)**
- **equal to compare: (1/2) N (N - 1)**
- **array access: N (N - 1)**
- **increment: (1/2) N (N - 1)  to  N (N - 1)**

First two are clear two, but I can't understand the weight of last operations: *"less than compare"* and *"equal to compare"*

For *"equal to compare"* **N + 1** is clear - it's like in 1-sum loop.

But what is the **(1/2)(N + 2)**?

Comment: Sorry, I added all parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the nested loop you're going to do the innermost evaluation `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + N` times.  The sum of the integers from one to `N` is `N*(N+1)/2`.  However, you need one more comparison on each loop to discover the termination condition, so the total number of comparisons is `(N+1)*(N+2)/2`.  Either way, it's O(N<sup>2</sup>) when you get introduced to big-O notation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to calculate how many times the implementation performs the *less-than* comparison (this is my guess on what "less than compare" means).

The calculation is based on the 1-sum variant; you said it was clear, but let me explain it for a start.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    ...
```

This loop performs the following comparisons:

```
Compare 0 with N
Compare 1 with N
Compare 2 with N
...
Compare N-1 with N
Compare N with N
```

Total: `N+1` comparisons. So now we know that the number of comparisons is 1 more than the number of iterations.

Now for the 2-sum variant:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
```

The inner loop performs `N-i` iterations, and so it does `N-i+1` comparisons, for each `i`. The outer loop performs N iterations, so it does `N+1` comparisons. So the total number of comparisons can be described as follows:

- N+1 comparisons of the outer loop
- N+1 comparisons of the inner loop for `i=0`
- N comparisons of the inner loop for `i=1`
- N-1 comparisons of the inner loop for `i=2`
- ...
- 2 comparisons of the inner loop for `i=N-1`

All these numbers make a sequence of consecutive numbers (you can replace the `N+1` and `2` by `N+2` and `1`), whose sum is easily calculated.

And well, it's actually `1/2*(N+3)(N+2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try some simpler things first:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
  *do something*
```

This will do something N times.

Now a nested loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = 1; j < N; j++)
    *do something*
```

This will do something N<sup>2</sup> times.

Now a different nested loop:

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
  for (int j = i; j < N; j++)
    *do something*
```

This will do something N(N+1)/2 times.

Work through the same sequence with the loops starting at 0, and count the "<" comparisons, and you'll get (N+1)(N+2)/2.